# iOS: How to make the button able to call function when only drag over it

Tags: ios

There are a bunch of buttons on the screen. If I drag a touch to the several of these buttons, How can I made it triggered all. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You question is not clear, what are you saying ?

Comment: Clue: `UIControlEventTouchDragInside`

Comment: Every button should trigger a different action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have tried with touch events?

For example:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        if (!buttonArray)
            buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [buttonArray removeAllObjects];
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && ![buttonArray containsObject:touch.view])
    {
        [buttonArray addObject:touch.view];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UIButton * button in buttonArray)
        [self buttonEvent:button];
}

-(void)buttonEvent:(UIButton *)but
{
    NSLog("buttonEvent :%@", but);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define a regular Action as you do. And then attach the Action with one of the following `Sent Events` in Connections Inspector ( make sure button in IB is clicked ) according to your requirements:

```
Touch Drag Enter
Touch Drag Exit
Touch Drag Inside
Touch Drag Outside
```

Remember: There is many-to-many relationship between `UIView`s and Actions. One `UIView` can be attached to many Actions, and one Action can be triggered by sending events on Multiple `UIView`s.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of, or possibly in addition to, the typical sending an event when it is `Touch Up Inside`, add an action that uses `Touch Drag Exit`. The action will be invoked when a user drags their finger outside of the button area. The image below show the Connections Inspector for the selected Send button and all of the possible send events.

[image]